# I cannot make the mental leap from a vector to a function!

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

In my linear algebra book, it says that a vector is linearly independent if

$\vec V = c1*\vec T_1 + c2*\vec T_2$

And then it goes on to say that

$y(t) = c1 * e^{-at} + c2*e^{-bt}$

is linearly independent

My mind cannot comprehend how an analogy can be made in this case. Is there a rigorous theorem some where that says a function is an infinite dimensioned vector? Only then can I completely appreciate linear algebra.

Thanks

Comment: Your definition on linear independent is not correct / complete.

Then you can consider functions as vectors because the set of real functions is a vector space. Good exercise for you to prove it! This vector space is indeed of infinite dimension.

Comment: I am sure your book does NOT say "a vector is linearly independent if $v=c_1t_1+c_2t_2$." Precise statements of definitions and examples are crucial towards getting anywhere in Mathematics; please consult your book, and let us know what it *really* says.

Comment: Go back to your linear algebra book and make sure what it is saying. – "Linear independence" is a property of **sets** of vectors. A one element set $\{v\}$  is linearly independent if  $v\ne0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, the *official* (Bourbaki) definition of a vector is as follows: a vector is an element of a vector space. For instance the elements of $\mathbf{R}^3$ are vectors; but the elements of the $\mathbf{R}$ vector space $\mathscr{F}(\mathbf{F},\mathbf{F})$ of all functions (maps) from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$ are also vectors (just because they are elements of a vector space!). One does not need a theorem here, this is merely about having the proper point of view; you only need to absorb the first sentence in this answer.

Comment: you have made it completely clear. thank you

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are somewhat confused about the use of "vectors" terminology.
In the context as mentioned, vectors are quite *abstract* things. In fact, they
are a *generalization* of the well known "geometric entities endowed with magnitude
and direction". See the Wikipedia page about 
[Vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)s ,
especially the section about *Function spaces* . (Note: this answer is partially a dunplicate of [Inner product of functions as integration](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882354/inner-product-of-functions-as-integration/882586#882586)).

Answer (score 3):

Vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent if the only solution to the equation $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0$ is the solution $c_1=c_2=0$. The functions $e^{-at}$ and $e^{-bt}$ are linearly independent, when considered as vectors, because (assuming $a\ne b$) the only values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ making $c_1e^{-at}+c_2e^{-bt}$ identically zero (that is, zero as a function; zero for all values of $t$) are $c_1=c_2=0$.