# Prove this collection is an orthonormal basis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\{g_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Prove that the collection $\{g_{k,j}\}_{1\leq j,k\leq \infty}$, where

$g_{k,j}(x,y)=g_{k}(x)g_{j}(y)$

is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$

My hint is to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^{2d}=\mathbb{R}^{d} \text{X} \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and use
the Fubini's theorem to verify the orthonormality. Then, I should again use Fubini's theorem regarding the case $(f,g_{k,j})=0$
for all $k,j$.

My problem is I have a hard time with the ideas regarding orthonormality so even the hint makes little sense to me.  Is that the same as saying something is an orthogonal projection? (I do have/know that definition at least). And, I have used and do understand Fubini's theorem.  I'm not really seeing the big connection though.

Comment: Perhaps helpful : [I cannot make the mental leap from a vector to a function!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113121/i-cannot-make-the-mental-leap-from-a-vector-to-a-function) .

Comment: Do you know what it means for vectors $u_1,u_2,\dots $ to be orthonormal in an inner product space?

Comment: Fix $n\ge1$ and let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Then

$0=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(x,y)g_{n}(x)g_{m}(y)d(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}f(x,y)g_{n}(x)dx\right)g_{m}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}F(y)g_{m}(y)dy$

Use completeness to conclude $F=0$. Hope this helps you complete the proof.

Comment: zhw - Yes, I get the concept.

Comment: user71352, Thanks for the start!  Han de Bruijn -- thanks for the link. Trying to understand that one now :)